# Инициализация сегментов в начале программы x86

Tags: ассемблер, x86

Я только недавно начал изучать ассемблер, возник вопрос: в начале программы в сегментный регистр DS мы передаём адрес регистра данных:

```
mov ax, @data (либо DATASEG (если не объявляем модели памяти)
mov DS, ax
```

Почему мы не делаем аналогичным образом для сегмента кода и сегмента стека?

Comment: Сегмент кода поменять можно только передачей управления, что и делает для нас операционная система после того, как загрузила программу в память. Сегмент стека настраивается операционной системой до начала выполнения, так как она должна положить в этот самый стек адрес возврата во время передачи выполнения. И я подозреваю, что некий сегмент данных ОС так же назначает при загрузке и надо ли его переопределять в вашей ОС и с вашим компилятором - это еще вопрос (ОС вполне может найти его в exe если он один)